# Load javascript function and when its loaded load it again in a specified number of seconds

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, reload

He guys,

Maybe you can help me, i need a code when the page is loaded a function (below)

```
 function update() {
     $('#animation').load('/Stream/readLevel');
 }
```

needs to execute, when this action is complete (so the content of the page /Stream/readLevel has been fully loaded the function must be loaded again in a number of seconds (2 seconds).

How can i accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you only want to reload after the contents has been fully loaded you have to set the timer in `success` callback of [`$.load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function like following,  otherwise it will send request to server every two seconds irrespect of if the previous ajax request has been completed or not.

```
function update() {
     $('#animation').load('/Stream/readLevel',function(){
        var timer = setTimeout(update,2000);
     });
 } 
$(function(){
   update();
});
```

Comment: This is so far the only answer that does what the op asked

Comment: Somebody should not edit my answer and add contents like that :s

Comment: @Adil that's not what the OP wants.. he doesn't want to blindly spam the server every 2 seconds but to send request after 2 seconds of fully loading the previous request..

Comment: @MarcoVeenendaal,  If this answer works for you, please [check the little check-mark next to it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1):

you can do it like this.

```
$(function(){    
   update();
});


function update() {
   $('#animation').load('/Stream/readLevel', function(){
       alert("after two seconds of load");
       setTimeout('update()', 2000);
  }); 
}
```

​

Comment: I've tried this but when the page is not fully loaded no action is performed on my site (this is a piece of code in readLevel code:   echo '$("#'.$player_name . '").animate({ width: "'. $player_width . 'px",height: "' . $player_height . 'px",}, 3000 );';
) so this animate action doesn't work (every 2 seconds)

Comment: that's not what the OP wants.. he doesn't want to blindly spam the server every 2 seconds but to send request after 2 seconds of fully loading the previous request..

Comment: still not correct, the interval will almost always fire 2 requests before it is cleared. You want to use setTimeout and at that point your answer is just copypaste of the correct one and doesn't contribute anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function update(){ 
    $('#animation').load('/Stream/readLevel',function(){
    setTimeout(update,2000); });

}
```

Comment: Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`.

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble That will trigger the evil `eval`.

Comment: So fast Dcoder changed his name to Joy.Iam Impressed.BTW @Joy thanks for answering

Comment: Nop, I didn't change my name. :(

Comment: that's not what the OP wants.. he doesn't want to blindly spam the server every 2 seconds but to send request after 2 seconds of fully loading the previous request..

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function update() {
    $("#animation").load('/Stream/readLevel',"",function(){
        setTimeout(update,2000);
    });
}
</script>

<body onload="update()">
  // HTML CODE
</body>
```

Comment: that's not what the OP wants.. he doesn't want to blindly spam the server every 2 seconds but to send request after 2 seconds of fully loading the previous request..

Answer (score 0):

var c = 2;
    function update() {
    $('#animation').load('/Stream/readLevel');
    }
    function startTimer(){

```
if(c< 0){
c=2;
}
if(c==2){
update();
}
timer = setTimeout('startTimer()',1000);
c=c-1;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
startTimer();
});
```